# Getting a named value in Excel - like a global variable

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I often have a sheet in my Excel spreadsheets, that contain some global values I use all over. for example a VAT rate or a currency exchange rate.

I can access one of these "global values" something like this:

```
Settings!$B$2
```

Say that cell contains the global VAT rate.

Is it possible to easily assing a variable name like `VATRATE`, so I could just type `$VATRATE` (or some other named syntax) to use it in a formula - but it would still be updated from cell `Settings!$B$2`.

Comment: Yes it's possible,, use Named Range,,, `Ctrl+F3`, and anytime you can use it anywhere, with formula. Also Named Range should dynamic too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to achieve this and the process involves creation of "Named Range".
For reproducing your scenerio, I have made two excel sheets here - one of them named as "Settings". Let's say, you have a value of `VatRate` equal to `20` in Settings!$B$2.

Now go to `Formulas` tab and click `Name Manager`. Click on `New` and create your Named Range by giving it a name, scope of that name and the reference cell address:

[image]

*(Be aware that you cannot use space in named range but can include underscore or period)*

Click "OK" and close it. Now, head to another sheet in the same workbook where you want to use it, here I used 'Sheet2'.

Enter in the cell, a formula. For example, `=SUM(VatRate, 0)`. It will result in the Sum of the value of VatRate *i.e*. 20 and 0 which will output `20` in that cell in '**Sheet2**':

[image]

**ADDITIONAL:** *For Dynamic Named Range*, you can do the same by tweaking this process a bit and using `OFFSET` functionality. If you have a column named "Vat Rate" in the "Settings" sheet, and want to update the value in other sheets automatically when you enter a value in that range of cells, edit the Named Range and use this formula:

`=OFFSET(Settings!$B$2,0,0,COUNTA(Settings!$B:$B),1)`

So, when you enter multiple values in that specified data range:

[image]

It will automatically reflect in the formula in the next worksheet:

[image]

There you go. I hope this helps :)

Comment: it's quit helpful,,, add one more,, how to create dynamic named range,, ☺

Comment: There it is, have a look :)

Comment: @Sanu_012,, you can even use any of the values ( or elements of an array ) from Named Range like `=INDEX(VatRate,2)` returns `15`. And if use this ,,`=SUM(VatRate,2):INDEX(VatRate,5))` will SUM `B3:B6`.